# Gui Api Java Programm Программа

Tags: java, swing, gui

Дело такое: есть программа, которая выводит рандомные "ответы" на вопросы. Что-то вроде шара предсказаний. Я уже реализовал интерфейс, вывод всплывающего окна, но проблема в том, что при компиляции программы выводится интерфейс и одновременно всплыв. окно. А нужно, чтобы ответ выходил после нажатия кнопки. Пытался сделать с помощью оператора if и типа boolean, но не вышло. Вот код:

```
public class Prigramm extends JFrame {
    private JButton button = new JButton("Press");
        private JLabel label = new JLabel("Prigramm");
    private JTextField EBox = new JTextField();

        public Prigramm(){
            super("Prigramm");
            this.setBounds(100, 100, 250, 100);
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            Container cont = this.getContentPane();
            cont.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 3, 2, 3));
            cont.add(label);
            cont.add(EBox);
            cont.add(button); }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
                Prigramm app = new Prigramm();
        app.setVisible(true);                                      
                Random r = new Random();
                for(int i=0; i <1; i++){
                    int q=r.nextInt(5);
                    if(0==q)JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Definitely yes");
                    if(1==q)JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Probably not");  
                    if(2==q)JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Most likely yes, but it is not known");  
                    if(3==q)JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Probably yes");  
                    if(4==q)JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You have no chance");
```

P.S. Я новичок. только учусь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам стоит разобраться в принципиальных отличиях в разработке консольных программ и программ с графическим интерфейсом.Архитектура вторых построена на системе делегирования события и в случае с некими затратными операциями следующими за реакцией слушателя события использованием отдельного потока для вышеупомянутых вычислений (сразу упомяну не ваш случай, эта информация для общего развития)
Итак чего не хватает Вам принимая во внимание все выше написанное?Слушателя события и реакции на событие:

```
button.addActionListener((l) -> {
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        int q = r.nextInt(5);
        if (0 == q)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Definitely yes");
        if (1 == q)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Probably not");
        if (2 == q)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Most likely yes, but it is not known");
        if (3 == q)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Probably yes");
        if (4 == q)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have no chance");
    }
});
```

**UPD:**

код:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Prigramm extends JFrame {
    private JButton button = new JButton("Press");
    private JLabel label = new JLabel("Prigramm");
    private JTextField EBox = new JTextField();

    public Prigramm() {
        super("Prigramm");
        this.setBounds(100, 100, 250, 100);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Container cont = this.getContentPane();
        cont.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 3, 2, 3));
        cont.add(label);
        cont.add(EBox);
        cont.add(button);
        button.addActionListener((l) -> {
            Random r = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                int q = r.nextInt(5);
                if (0 == q)
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Definitely yes");
                if (1 == q)
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Probably not");
                if (2 == q)
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Most likely yes, but it is not known");
                if (3 == q)
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Probably yes");
                if (4 == q)
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have no chance");
            }
        });

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Prigramm app = new Prigramm();
        app.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку. Кажется, это из-за ); в конце. А обязательны знаки ->?

Comment: Понятно данный блок должен располагатся в конструкторе Prigramm()  а не в методе main.  Касательно второй части вопроса это называется лямбда выражение

Comment: Да вот, как ни старайся- не получается. Выдает ошибку.

Comment: @МиронФисенко скопируйте готовый и проверенный код.На будущее    " *Выдает ошибку.*" не коментарий.Всегда указывайте какую ошибку выдает или какое исключение выбрасывает

Comment: Ладно, постараюсь сам найти выход, спасибо за совет!